# RxJS combineLatest function can be imported from both rxjs and rxjs/operators, what is the difference between the two?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

The *combineLatest* function can be imported either from *rxjs* and from *rxjs/operators*.

When I import it from *rxjs/operators* (just like I import *combineAll* I get the following error:

```
TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<{}, [{}, number, number, number]>'
```

I used the following code snippet:

```
import { timer } from "rxjs";
import { combineLatest } from "rxjs/operators";

const timerOne = timer(1000, 2500);
const timerTwo = timer(1500, 2500);
const timerThree = timer(2000, 2500);

//when one timer emits, emit the latest values from each timer as an array
const combined$ = combineLatest(timerOne, timerTwo, timerThree);

combined$.subscribe(
     ([timerValOne, timerValTwo, timerValThree]) => console.log(`Timer One Latest: ${timerValOne}, Two Latest: ${timerValTwo}, Three Latest: ${timerValThree}`)
);
```

Therefore, I tried to import it from *rxjs* instead of *rxjs/operators* :

```
import { combineLatest } from "rxjs";
```

And suddenly it worked. Nice, but can anyone explain what the difference is between the two?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. `import { combineLatest } from "rxjs";`

   This is so-called "Observable creation method". Basically a method that returns an Observable based on the arguments you pass it (just like `from()` or `of()`). Since it return an instance of `Observable` it has the `subscribe()` method.
2. `import { combineLatest } from "rxjs/operators";`

   This is an operator supposed to be used inside an operator chain. It's a method that returns another method that subscribes to the preceding Observable and returns another Observable that processes every value going through on its output.

That's why it gives you the error *`Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type....`*. The `subscribe()` method doesn't exist on a method returned from `combineLatest()` operator (it returns yet another function).

Comment: Nice answer, i just want to add : [According to documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md) `combineLatest` operator is deprecated now.

Comment: `combineLatest` is not deprecated. Only its variants with the ["result selector method"](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#result-selectors-removed-or-deprecated). In more detail https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/combineLatest.ts#L14-L43